# How can I add memory to an Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, virtual, ram

Is it possible to add a "custom" size memory to an Azure virtual machine?

For example, I'm using the Medium size - 2 core, 4GB RAM, I would like to have 8GB RAM with the current settings I have... otherwise the next option available is A5 2 core with 14GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft recently added a Large (A3) machine with 7GB
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/

Answer (score 23):

At https://portal.azure.com/ you can select the machine, then go to Size and pick another size for your virtual machine. It currently looks a bit like this:

[image]

If you scroll down see you a lot of different configurations, but you can't customize parameters of any of the given configurations.

See also [How to: Change the Size of a Windows Azure Virtual Machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn168976(v=nav.70).aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: Does resizing my VM, deletes the data on my old VM. For instance, I have a VM that hosts postgress, so does resizing remove my postgress?

Comment: @SuhasChikkanna I just tried it and seems like just the machine specs changed, the files and folders stayed the same.

Answer (score 20):

Simple answer is you can't. You will need to pick up from one of the existing VM sizes.

Comment: Changing size of Azure VM is now possible.